# cannot read properties of undefined split

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get the values of _clickHref and _pageName, however if I use the code:

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
var _clickHref = jQuery(this).attr('{{Referrer}}');
var _pageName= _clickHref.split('/').filter(Boolean);
_pageName = _pageName[_pageName.length-1];
  
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'special_offer',
      'carouselHref' : _clickHref,
      'modelName': _pageName
    });
  });
```

I get the error 'cannot read properties of undefined split'

and when I write the code:

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
var _clickHref = jQuery(this).attr('{{Referrer}}');
var _pageName= undefined;
  
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'special_offer',
      'carouselHref' : _clickHref,
      'modelName': _pageName
    });
  });
```

'carouselHref'is undefined. how to get the values of both carousalHref and modelName?

Comment: What do you think `this` is in the `.ready()` function?

Comment: You need to use `$('selector').attr(...)`, with the appropriate selector for the element whose attribute you want to get.

Comment: its the page after i submit a form. If I am right, the referrer should tell which page is it redirected from

Comment: That's `document.referrer` it's not an HTML attribute

Comment: I am still learning jQuery;
` jQuery().ready(function(){
var _clickHref = jQuery(this).document('{{Referrer}}');
var _pageName= undefined;
  
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'special_offer',
      'carouselHref' : _clickHref,
      'modelName': _pageName
    });
  }); 
`
isthis how I should write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referrer is in `document.referrer`, not an attribute.

```
var _clickHref = document.referrer;
```